# jekyll/liquid: given key access value from hash in template

Tags: jekyll, liquid

given the following code in a jekyll template

```
{% assign resource = site.data.resources | where: "id", page.resource %}
```

that derives the following hash:

```
{
  "id"=>"resource-1234", 
  "title"=>"testing", 
  "description"=>"Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui"
}
```

How do I user liquid to output the value of the title key?  I have tried the following:

```
{{ resource }}     # outputs the hash
{{ resource.title }}   # nil
{{ resource["title"] }}   # nil
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, the `where` filter returns an array.

When you print this array with `{{ resource }}`, it simply output all items one after an other. Here it print your hash, And this makes you think that `resource` is a hash.

For debugging you can use `{{ resource | inspect }}` that will return :

```
[{"id"=>"resource-1234", "title"=>"testing", "description"=>"Quis ..."}]
```

And here you see the brackets, and you know that `resource` is an array.

In your case, you know that only one (or zero) resource is linked to your page. In order to get only the first resource hash, you can do :

```
{% assign resource = site.data.resources | where: "id", page.resource | first %}
```

Now `{{ resource.title }}` returns `testing`.

Cool isn't it ?