# How to check if `folderitem` is the first array element in Jekyll (Liquid)?

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

The following code is supposed to add an `<h1>` for every page in PDF output. Basically, it steps through the YAML file that defines my guide and, if the URL of the current page matches the URL in the YAML block, it places the `title` key of the parent block within an `<h1>` tag.

```
{% assign sidebar = site.data.sidebars[page.sidebar].entries %}
    
{% for entry in sidebar %}
  {% for folder in entry.folders %}
    {% if folder.title and folder.type != "navi" and folder.type != "frontmatter" %}
      {% for folderitem in folder.folderitems %}
        {% if folderitem.url == page.url %}
<h1 class="post-title-main" id="{{page.permalink | replace: '/', '' }}">{{ folder.title }}</h1>
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is that the current code does this for *every* page, like this:

```
<h1>The Title I Want to Put in the H1</h1>
<h2>The Title of the Page Which I *Do* Want the <H1> to Appear Above</h2>
. . .
<h1>The Title I Want to Put in the H1</h1>
<h2>The Title of the Page Which I *Don't* Want the <H1> to Appear Above</h2>
```

I need another conditional check, something like "if `folderitem` is the first one" that would let the rest of the conditional logic proceed *only* if the item is the first in the list, resulting in:

```
<h1>The Title I Want to Put in the H1</h1>
<h2>The Title of the Page Which I *Do* Want the <H1> to Appear Above</h2>
```

What is the syntax for selecting the first item? `first` appears to be for *returning* the first item of an array, which doesn't seem to apply to *checking* if the current item is the first item in the YAML data structure that I'm working with.

Here's an example YAML structure:

```yaml
entries:
- title:
  pdftitle: foobar.pdf
  product:
  version:
  folders:

  - title:
    output: pdf
    type: frontmatter
    folderitems:

    - title:
      url: /titlepage.html
      output: pdf
      type: frontmatter

  - title: My Amazing Guide
    output: web
    type: navi
    folderitems:

    - title: Home
      url: /index.html
      output: web

- title: The Title I Want to Put in the H1
    url: /section/page/index.html
    output: web, pdf
    folderitems:

    - title: The Title of the Page Which I *Do* Want the <H1> to Appear Above
      url: /section/page/some-page.html
      output: web, pdf

    - title: The Title of the Page, Which I *Don't* Want the <H1> to Appear Above
      url: /section/page/another-page.html
      output: web, pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of

```
{% if folderitem.url == page.url %}
```

I was able to use

```
{% if folderitem.url == page.url and forloop.first == true %}
```

This additional condition does, in fact, check precisely what I wanted to check—whether the array item is first. Ironically (because I'm writing documentation?), the problem is that the Liquid documentation on https://shopify.github.io/liquid/ is incomplete, whereas the Liquid documentation on https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/ is far more comprehensive.

Here is [the documentation on `forloop.first`](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/forloop#forloop-first). It is here that I also learned that I could use properties like `forloop.index` (1-based), `forloop.index0`, and so forth.

Comment: Nice. Good to see that you solved it. Thanks for sharing this helpful link to the API docs. The described trick is pretty common to generate JSON files. Cool that it also works out for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Idea from: [jekyll/liquid: given key access value from hash in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38396538/jekyll-liquid-given-key-access-value-from-hash-in-template)

Could not test it but could something like this help you in your loop?

```
{% assign first_url= site.data.sidebars[page.sidebar].entries | where: "url", page.url | first %}`
```

Comment: I think you've answered my question in terms of how I could use `first` (by creating a `where` statement), but I was looking for something more like what I discovered on one of the other Liquid documentation sites (see my answer below).